# Whether given number is a power of any other natural number php?

Tags: php, pow

I tried to find For a given positive integer Z, check if Z can be written as P<sup>Q</sup>, where P and Q are positive integers greater than 1. If Z can be written as P<sup>Q</sup>, return `1`, else return `0`

I tried lots with online solution,

[Check if one integer is an integer power of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429044/check-if-one-integer-is-an-integer-power-of-another)

[Finding if a number is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965301/finding-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2)

but it's not what i need , any hint or any tips?

Comment: you want to loop 1 through infinity to test?

Comment: Here's condition , 1<= Z >= 10^9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the naive method - try every combination:

```
function check($z) {
    for($p = 2; $p < sqrt($z); $p++) {

        if($z % $p > 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $q = $p;

        for($i = 1; $q < $z; $i++) {
            $q *= $p;
        }

        if($q == $z) {
            //print "$z = $p^$i";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly, using php's built in `log` function. But it may not be as accurate (if there are rounding errors, false positives may occur).

```
function check($z) {
    for($p = 2; $p < sqrt($z); $p++) {
        $q = log($z,$p);
        if($q == round($q)) {
            return 1;
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}
```